# How can I remove default seekbar stroke?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is it possible to remove default seekbar stroke?

[image: Seekbar, when it's pressed]

Comment: Can you check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xml, you can add background, same

```
<SeekBar
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@null"/>
```